# How to create a method with an object wildcard (parameter) in Java?

Tags: java

```
Problem<NQueensBoard, QueenAction> problem = new GeneralProblem<>(createBoard(),
TailoredNQF::getIFActions, TailoredNQF::getResult, TailoredNQF::testGoal);

SearchForActions<NQueensBoard, QueenAction> search = new BreadthFirstSearch<>(new GraphSearch<>());
Optional<List<QueenAction>> actions = search.findActions(problem);
actions.ifPresent(qActions -> qActions.forEach(System.out::println));
System.out.println(search.getMetrics());
```

I want "BreadthFirstSearch" to be some kind of a wildcard(*) (or parameter in a method structure) here, so that I can run this entire piece of code just as;

```
runCode(BreadthFirstSearch);
runCode(DepthFirstSearch);
...
```

without repeating.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an `interface` or an `abstract class` and `dependency injection`, to inject the type of object search you want to do. The code will look something like this:

```
public interface SearchForAction<N, Q> {
    Optional<List<Q>> findActions(Problem<N, Q> problem);
}

public class BreadthFirstSearch implements SearchForAction<N, Q> {
    Optional<List<Q>> findActions(Problem<N, Q> problem) {
        // Do your action
    }    
}

public class SearchEngine<N, Q> {
    
    private SearchForAction<N, Q> searchForAction;
    public Optional<List<Q>> runCode(SearchForAction<N, Q> searchForAction, Problem<N, Q> problem) {
        this.searchForAction = searchForAction;
        return this.searchForAction.findActions(problem);
    }
}

public class Program {

    private SearchEngine<NQueensBoard, QueenAction> searchEngine = new SearchEngine<>();
    private SearchForActions<NQueensBoard, QueenAction> breadthFirstSearch = new BreadthFirstSearch<>();
    private SearchForActions<NQueensBoard, QueenAction> depthFirstSearch = new DepthFirstSearch<>();

    // In your program call your method and you inject your dependency
    searchEngine.runCode(breadthFirstSearch);
    searchEngine.runCode(depthFirstSearch);
}
```